# Angular16 404 route isn't called on invalid routes

Tags: angular, angular-router

I' having trouble figuring out how to get my 404 route to load when I enter a path that doesn't match any of my other routes. the way I have my routes set up goes as follows

```
const SITEROUTES: Routes = [
    //...routes
    {
        path:'',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        loadComponent: () => import('./pages/site/page-not-found-page/page-not-found-page.component')
        .then(mod => mod.PageNotFoundPageComponent)
    }
]
```

All my routes load as expected so I didn't feel it was important to include them.  The reason I'm showing these two is because if I add a route that doesn't match any of my other routes it defaults to the `redirectTo` route instead of the wildcard route.  If I comment out the redirect route the wildcard route triggers as I want it to, however it also triggers if I don't provide a route.

I put these two routes last in the array and even added `pathMatch: 'full` to the wildcard route to see if it would make a difference and it didn't.  I'm also using `standalone` components for this app so I import the routes into my `main.ts` file as follows

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(SITEROUTES),
    provideAnimations()
  ]
};


bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I'm also switching routes programmatically through a `subscription` to a service file which I have set up in my `AppComponent` like this

```
constructor(private router: Router, private navService: SidebarService){
  this.navService.Route.subscribe(a => this.router.navigateByUrl(a));
}
```

Everything else works as I expect it to so I don't see a need to include any other code at the moment nor do I know what else would be relevant.  If you need to see something else let me know and I'll update the post to include it.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your route configuration

```
const SITEROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundPageComponent
  }
];
```

With this configuration, when the user enters a URL that doesn't match any of the other routes, the wildcard route with path: '**' will automatically capture it and load the PageNotFoundPageComponent.

Also, please ensure that you have imported the necessary components and the Routes and RouterModule from @angular/router

hope it's helpful..

Comment: So in other words, there's no way to get it to work with lazy loaded routes?

Comment: @Optiq You can definitely make it work with lazy-loaded routes and have a wildcard (404) route at the same time. The issue is not related to lazy-loaded routes but rather to the configuration of the wildcard route itself.

To make it work with lazy-loaded routes, you just need to adjust your wildcard route configuration. Instead of using loadComponent in the wildcard route, you should specify the component property, as I mentioned in my answer. This will allow the wildcard route to work correctly, regardless of whether the routes are lazy-loaded or not.

Comment: Splendid, but I'm still not clear on what the code will look like in that instance.